# How to check the path in a reference in a security rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to check that a resource has a reference to a user document when creating it, but I don't need to actually get() the object. Is this possible?

I know I can call `exists()` or `get()` but I really only care that the path is correct (that its for `/users/${auth.uid}`). This is for Firestore.

I would like to do something like:

```
allow create: if request.resource.userRef == '/users/${request.auth.uid}'
```

Although I know that is not possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query you want to restrict, along with the rules that don't work the way you expect.  Security rules are mostly meaningless unless there is a specific query you would like to allow or reject.  In your case, the `match` part of the rule is just as important as the `allow` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to check if the document contains the user's `uid` as the value of `userRef` field and the user with the corresponding `uid` exists in your users collection before saving the document.

In that case you need to make 2 checks.

1) Check if the user exists in `users` collection

2) Check if the document contains the user's `uid` in the `userRef` field of the document

```
//Get the user using uid
function getUser() {
   return (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data);
}

//Check if user exists
function isValidUser(user) {
        return (user != null);
}
// Check access for your collection 
match /YourCollection/{id} {
        allow create: if (isValidUser(getUser()) && request.resource.data.userRef == getUser().uid);
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you! This answers it. I was hoping it’s possible  without the first get() but that makes sense!